# AngularJS ng-click linking to a model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I am building a small rss reader using Express(ie Jade) and Angular. I have a dropdown menu, where the menu items are populated by a list of items in a model.
Whatever the user chooses as an item, there is a rss url attached to it and it should trigger a factory.
This is the jade part:

```
div.btn-group
    button.btn.btn-info(type='button') {{loadButtonText}}
    button.btn.btn-info.dropdown-toggle(data-toggle='dropdown')
        span.caret
        span.sr-only Toggle Dropdown
    ul.dropdown-menu(role='menu')
        li(ng-repeat='rss in RSSList')
            a(href='#', ng-click="feedSrc='{{rss.url}}';loadFeed($event);") {{rss.Title}}
        input.form-control(type='text', autocomplete='off', placeholder="This is where your feed's url will appear" data-ng-model='feedSrc')
```

This is my angular controller:

```
var News = angular.module('myApp', []);
News.controller('FeedCtrl', ['$scope','FeedService', function($scope, Feed){
    $scope.loadButtonText = 'Choose News Feed';
    $scope.RSSList = [
        {Title: "CNN", url: 'http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss'},
        {Title: "Reuters", url: 'http://feeds.reuters.com/news/usmarkets'}
    ];
    $scope.loadFeed = function (e) {
        Feed.parseFeed($scope.feedSrc).then(function (res) {
            $scope.loadButtonText=angular.element(e.target).text();
            $scope.feeds = res.data.responseData.feed.entries;
            }); }}]);
News.factory('FeedService', ['$http', function($http){
    return {parseFeed: function (url){
        return $http.jsonp('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=50&callback=JSON_CALLBACK&q='+encodeURIComponent(url));}}
}]);
```

It seems feedSrc in ng-click doesn't capture rss.url and can not be passed as argument to the parseFeed function.
I tried to pass rss.url directly into loadFeed, like this `ng-click="loadFeed({{rss.url}});"` and even `ng-click="loadFeed('{{rss.url}}');" I didn't work either.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to use just:

Jade:

```
a(href='#', ng-click="loadFeed(rss.url,$event)") {{rss.Title}}
```

Controller:

```
$scope.loadFeed = function (url, e) {
    Feed.parseFeed(url).then(function (res) {
      $scope.loadButtonText=angular.element(e.target).text();
      $scope.feeds = res.data.responseData.feed.entries;
 }); }}]);
```

Answer (score 6):

Simply pass it this way :

```
ng-click="loadFeed(rss.url)"
```

No need to use the {{ }} in ng-click